# Product of array elemetns

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to see better code/logic of the below questions from you guys.
Que: Say, there are two arrays - Input and Output array. Taking 4 elements in input array. O/p array will also have length of same as Input array. Output should have - first index value should product of all values from the rest of indexes except first. Similarly, second index value should have product of all other values from the rest of indexes except second. Likewise, the product should go till output array get the same length as that of input's. I have written code but I wanted to see different answers from different viewers. More customized and use of library functions is helpful. Customizing my code also is welcome.

```
System.out.println("Enter the size of the array..");
    scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan1.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the array elements..");
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = scan1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Array is.." +Arrays.toString(arr));
    int[] arr1 = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        int sum = 1, j = 0;
        while (j<arr.length){
            if(i==j)
                System.out.println("I and J are equal");
            else
                sum = sum * arr[j];
        j++;
        }arr1[i] = sum;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));`
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It should be on code review, but I'll add my two cents here. You should work out the product of all the numbers, and then make the new array by dividing this result by the each of the original numbers. That makes the process `O(n)`, whereas your version is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: You should also try to review your question before posting it on codereview. The description is currently hard to read. You should try to space it out, and I think the algorithm description could be more formal (given an input integer array, it produces and output array where ...)